# How to identify the exact row match between two dataframe and print the rows above it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe like mentioned below:

df1 =

```
        Symbol                   Subject   Broadcast Date/Time
0   CUMMINSIND  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 18:31
1          IGL  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 17:16
2   MANAPPURAM  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 16:10
3   MANAPPURAM            Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 16:00
4     JSWSTEEL  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 15:18
```

df2 =

```
        Symbol                   Subject   Broadcast Date/Time
0   MANAPPURAM  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 16:10
```

I want to find the location of exact value matching df2 row with df1 row.
And create result df3 with all the rows above the matching row.

df3 =

```
        Symbol                   Subject   Broadcast Date/Time
0   CUMMINSIND  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 18:31
1          IGL  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 17:16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`merge` to find the match and use `.iloc` to subset. `.reset_index` first so you can access the original index after the merge.

```
df1.iloc[:df1.reset_index().merge(df2)['index'].item()]

       Symbol                   Subject Broadcast Date/Time
0  CUMMINSIND  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 18:31
1         IGL  Financial Result Updates   06-Feb-2019 17:16
```

I like `.item()` because it will throw a `ValueError` if multiple rows match, while it seems like you only expect a single match. If you want to deal with the possibility of multiple matches then you can grab everything up until the last match with `.iloc[-1]` instead of `.item()`:

```
df1.iloc[:df1.reset_index().merge(df2)['index'].iloc[-1]]
```

If nothing matches you will get a `ValueError` with `.item()` or an `IndexError` with `.iloc`, so either catch them and return nothing or first check `df1.reset_index().merge(df2).empty` and return nothing in that case.

Comment: Thanks Sir for noce help. How can I store the result in df3 dataframe.

Comment: @Rohit  assign the above line to `df3` by doing `df3 = df1.iloc[:df1.reset_index().merge(df2)['index'].item()]`. Though I think you will need to add some Try Except cases or first check if the merge is empty to avoid errors for cases of multiple or non-matches.

Comment: Sir, Getting Error:  can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

Comment: @Rohit that is either because you have multiple matches, or no matches at all. Look at the output of `df1.reset_index().merge(df2)` If it's empty, nothing matched. If it's more than one row, multiple lines matched. You will need to decide how to handle those cases separately.

Comment: Yes added Try..Except to resolve that. Thanks a Lot.